# how to solve problems of configuration in agent SQL?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, analysisservices

I am doing a data warehousing project using SQL server for the analysis services database. This service works perfectly, but the problem is with the SQL agent. I created a job to do a daily ETL process with SISS packages. When I try to run that job it returns a configuration error in the connection manager (I bring data from postgre SQL with ODBC). The error it returns is the following (translated with google since it returns it in Spanish):

> Code: 0xC020801B Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [2] Description: Cannot find runtime connection manager with id. "{849459E5-813C-4707-810B-4C5214A362DA}". Check that the connection manager collection has a connection manager with that id. End of error Error: 2020-10-02 11: 12: 00.36 Code: 0xC0047017 Source: SSIS.Pipeline Data Flow Task Description: OLE DB Destination validation failed; error code 0xC020801B was returned.

The question is: how can I change this configuration so that in the connection manager it has the same id that SQL Server mentions?

Comment: How did you deploy the package? This smells like you've created a package with a project deployment method in mind and deployed in a package deployment mode.

Comment: could you guide me in this part? The only thing I did was create the package, establish a component for ODBC source and OLE DB destination. When I run it manually, it goes but not with the agent. Do not touch the package settings

Comment: *"but not with the agent"* which is why I ask what deployment method you used. That's what I need to know.

Comment: that is my question.. how can know wich is the deplyment method??

Comment: You're the one that deployed it... You know how and what you did to deploy it...

Comment: capable I'm not explaining myself well. Don't use any implementation "method" that I know of. Just configure the ODBC source component to fetch data from postgre and configure the OLE DB destination for the union of columns with the source ones. that's why I don't know what the "implementation method" would be

Comment: You're the that *deployed* the package. YOu're the one that set up Agent to run, said package.. Again, what did you d to **deploy** the package? What did you do for agent to run the deployed package...?

Comment: first I created a new job, then the first step (in this case a test that only has a first and last name). This step is of type "Integration Services SQL Package. It is executed as" SQL Server Agent Service account ", as it is a test I configure it to be executed every 2 minutes. It is all the configuration that I used

Comment: In the "package" tab I chose to view it from the file system and look for the package that I had created within the project. It is not within the SISS catalog of SQL server.

Comment: WEll, there's your problem, you're using a project level connection manager with a package deployed in msdb. Use SSISDB and deploy the **project**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parameterise the connection within the SSIS designer.

See [this article](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables)